# Fading elements in and out without changing the layout of the page

Tags: jquery, css, layout

The normal behavior when using [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) is to use [the `display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display). However, this changes the layout of the page.

How can I make `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` not modify the layout of the page?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Also

instead of `.fadeIn()` you can `.animate({opacity:1})`
and instead of `.fadeOut()` you can `.animate({opacity:0})`

Comment: When you animate opacity, clicks on elements still fire event handlers. With `visibility: hidden`, the events are *not* fired.

Comment: @Jawa, yes but visibility is not animated and the OP wants to *fade in/out*. (*you could add `visibility:hidden` once the animation is complete, through the `callback` parameter, to satisfy both needs*)

Answer (score 25):

You can try this for `fadeOut`:

```
$("something here").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).show().css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

...and this for `fadeIn`:

```
$("something here").hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to do this but was having trouble getting the fade out to work, that callback does the trick though.

Answer (score 18):

Use [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/):

> The `.fadeTo()` method animates the opacity of the matched elements. It is similar to the [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method but that method unhides the element and always fades to 100% opacity.
>
> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings `'fast'` and `'slow'` can be supplied to indicate durations of `200` and `600` milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, the default duration of `400` milliseconds is used. Unlike the other effect methods, `.fadeTo()` requires that `duration` be explicitly specified.
>
> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to 10gler my solution below, using visibility to prevent invisible button click, etc.

```
//fadeIn
$("#x")
    .css('visibility', 'visible')
    .fadeTo('fast', 1);

//fadeOut
$("#x")
    .fadeTo('fast', 0, function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of the above answers, this worked well for me. 
You can change the animation time to your liking.

To `fadeIn`:

```
        $('selector').animate({opacity:1, visibility:'visible'}, 200);
```

To `fadeOut`:

```
        $('selector').animate({opacity:0, visibility:'hidden'}, 200);
```

Make sure to set the `visibilty:'hidden'` and `opacity:0` at the start to avoid the sudden pop on the first fade in if the default display is hidden, otherwise it shouldn't matter.

```
        $('selector').css({opacity:0, visibility:'hidden'});
```