# jQuery Image fadeIn Upon Scroll Inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get the actually LazyLoad plugin to work for me so I am trying to write my own with. Currently I have a list of images loading inside of a DIV. They are pulled by a PHP query to the mysql database. The DIV scroll is set to auto. The code I am using is:

```
<div id="b1" style="overflow:auto;">
<?PHP $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<img src='$row[photo]' style='display:none'> <br>";

}

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function imgCheck() {
var position        = $("img").offset().top;            
var scrollCheck       = $("#b1").scrollTop() + $("#b1").height();
if ( scrollCheck > position) {
  $("img").fadeIn("fast");
   }


$("#b1").scroll( function() { imgCheck() } );
</script>
```

Although this is not quite working for me. Could anyone help me out or shoot out some suggestions?

Comment: Could you further specify 'is not quite working for me'?

Comment: Yeah sorry, upon scrolling the DIV no images are faded in. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- As the others have already said, your code has syntax errors - both with the PHP and the Javascript.
- If you use `display: none`, the elements will not take up any height, thus causing the entire thing to become unscrollable and fail.
- The first few elements should be visible without the user having to start scrolling

Taking these into consideration, we can try writing this this way:

```
// Cache the containing element and it's height
var b1 = $('#b1'),
    h = b1.height();

// Insert 20 img's - simulating server-side code
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    $('<img />', {
        src: 'http://placehold.it/100x100',
        alt: '',
        class: 'hidden',
        width: 100,
        height: 100
        // visibility: hidden to retain it's size
    }).css('visibility', 'hidden').appendTo(b1);
}

b1.scroll(function(){
    // Loop through only hidden images
    $('img.hidden').each(function(){
        // $(this).position().top calculates the offset to the parent
        // So scrolling is already taken care of here
        if(h > $(this).position().top){
            // Remove class, set visibility back to visible,
            // then hide and fade in image
            $(this).css('visibility', 'visible')
                .hide()
                .removeClass('hidden')
                .fadeIn(300);
        } else {
            // No need to check the rest - everything below this image
            // will always evaluate to false - so we exit out of the each loop
            return false;
        }
    });
    // Trigger once to show the first few images
}).trigger('scroll');
```

**See a demo of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/eXSXm/2**

Comment: When i go to the link to check it out, nothing is happening for me. It is just displaying an empty DIV. Thanks by the way. Your always pulling me out of jams and helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @mcb I've updated the code because of a mistake I made in the earlier version. Does it work now?

Comment: very much so, thanks so much, i cant tell you how much i appreciate the help. your always helping me out, and once again you've done it. Don't know what I would do without the community and the great people on here.

Comment: Nice solution. Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

If all of the images are hidden, then there will never be a 'scroll' even called as the element will never scroll.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If it is to have new images that weren't previously visible, but now may be, become visible then you will have to do something like;

```
<div id="b1" style="overflow:auto;">
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<img src='$row[photo]' style='visibility:hidden'> <br>";
} ?>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function imgCheck() {
    var scrollCheck = $("#b1").scrollTop() + $("#b1").height();

    $("#b1 img").each(function() {
        var position = $(this).offset().top;            
        if (scrollCheck > position) {
            $(this).fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(imgCheck);

$("#b1").scroll(imgCheck);
</script>
```

Note that I haven't tested the above, and I can imagine that it will result in all images being shown immediately, since all of their 'top's will be 0 due to them all being hidden and not having their position effected by previous images in the DOM.

**Edit**

I've changed the code above so the img's have visibility:hidden, which should give them a height and take up space in the DOM

Comment: what if i added an elemnt ontop of each image that was empty such as a placeholder for example:        echo "<div id='placeholder'></div><img src='$row[photo]' style='display:none'> <br>";         or if i wrapped each image in a DIV?

Comment: @Jess: yes, all of them are shown immediately after the first scroll.

Comment: yeah, i noticed that as well, after the intial scroll everything fades in. I dont think i did specify, so sorry about that, but I was looking to fade each in upon scrolling to their position. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated the code so it gives the images visibility:hidden, which should allow them to have a height in the DOM.

Comment: still not working out for me. Im still workin on it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing it, it seems to work with some modifications:

http://jsfiddle.net/antiflu/zEHtu/

Some things I had to change:

- I added the closing `}` for the `imgCheck()` function, you forgot it
- Some items need to be visible from the beginning on, otherwise the scrollbar never appears and imgCheck() is never called.

---

OK the problem with the above was that the images don't fade in separately upon scroll. I got it to work though with some modifications:

http://jsfiddle.net/antiflu/GdzmQ/

What I changed:

- I changed the `display: none` to `opacity: 0` so that any invisible picture has at least an empty placeholder of the same size, so that the scroll bar will be visible.
- I then fade in using [animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256400/jquery-fadein-fadeout-visibility) to `opacity: 1`
- I used jQuery `each()` to iterate over the images and check for each of them if they should or should not be faded in (instead of checking for all, like before).
- I wrapped the images in DIV's. I don't think it's necessary, but it doesn't harm either.
- I tagged each image with an `id`, so that I can single them out for the fadein.

There are still some esthetic issues but this should help you on your way.

Comment: Ah, i see that it does work on jsFiddle, i guess maybe i didn't specify that i am trying to get each image to fadeIn upon scrolling to its position. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yup, check the modified fiddle, it works better now. I will continue updating the answer to explain what I did.