# jQuery - Image starts off invisible then fades in when user scrolls

Tags: jquery

I'm very close to achieving an effect that I want, I just have one obstacle left that I don't know how to solve.

Basically, I want to start off with an image (that says "a new era of hosting), then, as the user scrolls, that image fades out, and a new one fades in, saying "tired of hosting with kids?"

I'm very close to achieving this effect. The only problem is, as the page loads, both of the images are visible, and the second one then disappears as you begin scrolling. How do I make it so that the second image isn't visible when the page loads?

Here is my jQuery code, which I was given from another question. Please note I haven't learnt jQuery yet, and so the way I have edited it may be amateurish or flat out wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var subsection2Top = $('.sub-section2').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (subsection2Top + 500 < y) {
            $('.sub-section2').fadeTo(100, 1);
        } else {
            $('.sub-section2').fadeTo(100, 0);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var subsectionTop = $('.sub-section').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (subsectionTop + 300 < y) {
            $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 0);
        } else {
            $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBHDb/) of all of my code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you only need one document.ready

Comment: Sound like you need to start the second image out hidden using CSS

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222300/jquery-image-fadein-upon-scroll-inside-div

Comment: Also why not use lazyload? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Not working in IE10, you may want to look into that.

Comment: IE10....the devils work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to ready function.

```
$('.sub-section2').hide();
```

Also i didn't get why you have two ready functions you could just write it once like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var subsection2Top = $('.sub-section2').offset().top;
var subsectionTop = $('.sub-section').offset().top;
$('.sub-section2').hide();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (subsection2Top + 500 < y) {
        $('.sub-section2').fadeTo(100, 1);
    } else {
        $('.sub-section2').fadeTo(100, 0);
    }
    if (subsectionTop + 300 < y) {
        $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 0);
    } else {
        $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 1);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect. As I said, I don't know jQuery yet, hence my stupid mistakes. :P

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix:
add this code just below the first document.ready call:

```
$(".sub-section2").css('opacity',0);
```

But I agree that you should really do this in your css file. jQuery just makes it easy to do cross-browser compatible css.

Answer (score 0):

For the second image use:

```
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HHxgCJH.png" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KBHDb/1/)

**Change**:

```
<section id="section-two" class="sub-section2" style="display: none;">
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <section id="section-one" class="sub-section">
        <article class="text-image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/c11oOSv.png" />
        </article>
    </section>
    <section id="section-two" class="sub-section2" style="display: none;">
        <article class="text-image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HHxgCJH.png" />
        </article>
    </section>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
    <p>Text so I can scroll</p>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var subsection2Top = $('.sub-section2').offset().top;
    var subsectionTop = $('.sub-section').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (subsection2Top + 500 < y) {
            $('.sub-section2').fadeTo(100, 1);
        } else {
            $('.sub-section2').fadeTo(100, 0);
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (subsectionTop + 300 < y) {
            $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 0);
        } else {
            $('.sub-section').fadeTo(100, 1);
        }
    });
});
```