# Firefox 3.6 and html5, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I built a site using HTML5 doctype and tags.  I was doing some browser testing and I found that one part didn't work in Firefox 3.6 (and FF 3.0.5, but we only support back to 3.6). Everything within my header tag doesn't show up at all.  nothing.  Firebug doesn't show an error either.

The weird thing is that only the items that are within the **header** don't work.  Everything in my **section**, **article**, **nav**, and **footer** tags work perfectly and are styled correctly.  I'm using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).  I even have my site working fine in IE6 using this html5 shiv.

What sets apart my **header** tag from the rest is that there are some basic jQuery fades happening within it. I'm hiding divs using css *visibility:hidden* so my layout is not altered.  My JS code is posted below. I'm using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2256404/395414) (the fadeIn one) to fadeIn my elements while keeping layout.

I want to also note that when I [turn on the Firefox 3.6 html5 parser](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2010/01/html5/enabling-the-html5-parser-in-firefox-3-6), which is apparent off by default in FF 3.6, it all works normally. But as I said before, even with the html5 parser off, the html5 tags that are not affected by jQuery are parsed just fine. Since I can't alter the end users config, I have to work around this.

All I have within my header tags are divs, h1, h2, h3, p, and anchor links.  No hgroups or other html5 tags whatsoever.  Just the header tag is it.

I have searched and tried many many different things and nothing works.

my js code:

```
var mySite = {
_delay : 2000,
init : function () {
    this._frame1();
    this.nextButton();
},
nextButton : function () { 
    var that = this;
    $('.next-button').click(function (e, a) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && a === 'auto') {
            that._frame2(a);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(that.timer);
            that._frame2('clicked');
        }
    });     
},
_frame1 : function () { 
    var first = function () { 
        $('#drug-info-1, .specific-info-small').hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn();
    };
    var second = function () {
        $('#drug-info-2').hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn();
    };
    var third = function () {
        $('#drug-info-3, .next-button').hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn();
    };

    setTimeout( first, this._delay);
    setTimeout( second, this._delay*2);
    setTimeout( third, this._delay*3);      
    this.timer = setTimeout( function () { $('.next-button').trigger('click', ['auto']); }, this._delay * 7);
},
_frame2 : function (a) {

    bye1 = function () {
        // fade out all of frame1 and then fadein first part of headline of frame2
        $('.frame1').fadeOut('slow' ,function () {
            $('.frame2').show();
            $('.frame2 h2, #headline-source').hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn();
        });                         
    };
    fourth = function () {
        $('#clinical-studies').hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn();
    };

    fifth = function () {
        $('.learn-more-button, .important-safety').hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn();
    };

    if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && a === 'auto') {
        setTimeout( bye1, this._delay * 2);
    } else {
        bye1();
    }       
    setTimeout( fourth, this._delay * 3);
    setTimeout( fifth, this._delay * 4);
}
};
$(document).ready(function () {
     mySite.init();                             
});
```

Comment: Just as a test, can you load html5shiv for testing in Firefox 3.6?  That's assuming you have an IE conditional for loading html5shiv.  I always try to start with the easiest thing.

Comment: I tried that too.  didn't work.  I also tried changing my header to a div with id of header and it didn't work.  I'm probably going to have to change my doctype and replace all my html5 tags.  I'm just trying to figure out a way that I don't have to do that.  I thought it was supposed to gracefully degrade. oh well

Comment: Can we get a http://jsfiddle.net/ for this?

Comment: thank you @drew! your jsfiddle comment helped my figure out.  It was a jQuery version issue. I was on the latest 1.7.2,  but when I was setting up the jsfiddle they only went up to 1.7.1 and it worked.  So I went and changed it on my local version and that did it!

Comment: Cool.  Glad it worked out.  Seems like a bug.  Maybe worth while submitting it.  http://bugs.jquery.com/search?ticket=on