# Seuqentially FadeIn and FadeOut Elements Nested in DIVs

Tags: jquery

(Hi guys) I am trying to create a scenario where `<li>` elements fade in and fade out one after another - ***which I can get to work.***

I am also trying to stop the animation process when I hover over an `<li>` element that is currently being animated - ***which I can also get to work.***

However I am having trouble being able to show an `<li>` element once it has been set to display:none, instead I have to wait for the animation to cycle through.

#### This is my current HTML markup;

```
<div id="content">
    <li class="one">one</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</div>
```

However I thought if I could nest the `<li>` elements within a  which does not get hidden by my jQuery, then I could set the `<li>` element back to display:block when I mouse over the `<div>`.

#### Suggested markup;

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrap"><li class="one">one</li></div>
    <div class="wrap"><li class="two">two</li></div>
    <div class="wrap"><li class="three">three</li></div>
</div>
```

However with my jQuery pasted below you can see that it only treats the `<li>` elements if they are siblings of #content and not if they are nested.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#content li').hide();
    InOut($('#content li:first'));

    function InOut(elem) {
        elem.delay().fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500, function() {
            if (elem.next().length > 0) {
                InOut($(this).next());
            }
            else {
                InOut($(this).siblings(':first'));
            }

        });
    }

    $('#content li').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(500).stop(true, true);
    });
    $('#content li').mouseout(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
            InOut($(this));
        }
    });

});
```

For the sake of an example I have created a Fiddle of the current animation in sequence below;

http://jsfiddle.net/pusher/TuGES/1/

Any help is always appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow a mouseover on the hidden elements, you have to not use `fadeOut()` because that leaves the item as display: none which won't receive mouse events.  Instead, you need to leave it with an opacity of 0 which means you need to use `fadeTo()`.  Here's a fixed version of the code (with time intervals shortened for testing).

I've fixed it so it has the following behavior:

- When you mouseover an item that is fading out, it pops back to full visibility and all animation stops.
- When you mouseover an item that is fading in, it pops to full visibility and all animation stops.
- When you mouseover an item that was visible, it holds that item as visibility and no animation starts.
- When you mouseout of an item, it starts the animation.
- When you mouseover a hidden item, it shows that one immediately and hides all others.

One of the keys to the fix was to stop all animation and `.hide()` all other elements (that may have been animating) because that's the normal finished state of `.fadeOut()` which will allow the animation to start up again it's normal way.  After hiding all elements, we show the current one and set it's opacity to 1 to get it in the fully visible state.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#content li').css("opacity", 0);
    InOut($('#content li:first'));

    function InOut(elem) {
        elem.delay().fadeTo(1500, 1).delay(1000).fadeTo(1500, 0, function() {
            if (elem.next().length > 0) {
                InOut($(this).next());
            }
            else {
                InOut($(this).siblings(':first'));
            }

        });
    }

    $('#content li').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).siblings().add(this).stop(true, false).css("opacity", 0);
        $(this).show().css("opacity", 1);
    });
    $('#content li').mouseout(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
            InOut($(this));
        }
    });
});​
```

And, here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/k4ASz/

P.S. I had to update your CSS a bit too because with all items in the page at all times, the layout is a bit different.

Comment: Hi Jfriend, thanks for that... I am trying to access any `<li>` element that is hidden if I mouse over or click in the area in which it exists. So really I am trying to modify the default behavior of fadeIn/fadeOut from display:none to visibility:hidden so then either mouseover or click would still work. If I mouseover/click a hidden `<li>` then the current element that is animating should fade out. On mouseout or click the animation resumes. The click function is for mobile devices i.e. iphone/ipad.

Comment: @userabuser - OK, that was not clear from your original question - perhaps why nobody answered that.  In that case, you need to use fadeTo() so only the opacity is set and you have to change your CSS.  I will put up a fixed version in a second.

Comment: @userabuser - I updated my answer to a newer version that lets you mouseover any item, even a hidden one and it will snap into view immediately and suspend all animation.

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I was after! I do notice though that until the animation has cycled through each `<li>` element that its not accessible via mouseover, however once it has shown the element at least once in the animation cycle you can then access those which are hidden! So thats definitely in the right direction. My explanation likely makes no sense as I've not been to sleep - sorry. But thank you for your contribution thus far!!

Comment: @userabuser - I fixed that issue with a change to the initialization code to make all three have `.css("opacity", 0)` instead of `.hide()`

Comment: Looks like I've solved that issue now by making a modification upon your modification! [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pusher/F2by9/2/)

Comment: @ jfriend00 Ah, ignore my link above then as I posted that and did not see your last modification which is a more elegant solution to what I've just done!

Comment: @userabuser - actually even better is to just set the initial opacity to 0 in the CSS.

Comment: Excellent, even better. Also incase anyone else wants to get this to work on iPhone/iPad with a "toggle" action here is a modification [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pusher/cSW2Y/2/) I'm assuming the best way is to detect the USER_AGENT and serve them the applicable jQuery depending on their device. Well you have been a **great help** jfriend! Really appreciate it a lot. Answer awarded as it should be...  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you set the display to "none" the element is actually no longer accessible outside of code. It makes changing content programatically great, but its not so great for clickables for users. I would suggest using visiblity:hidden instead.

Comment: Very good point... Though would you have an idea how I might incorporate some of what is found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256400/jquery-fadein-fadeout-visibility) into my jQuery?

Comment: Im not familiar enough with JQuery but through the use of the link you've posted it should be quite simple. I'm more of an Applications developer, not a web developer; I just know enough to get by. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. You did give me an idea of where to head and I did come up with a solution using visibility:hidden/visible with this Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pusher/F2by9/2/) - ultimately the answer below worked out being the most elegant solution. Appreciate your help! Thank you.