# jQuery callback freezing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**I made a little fiddle to illustrate the problem.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jphMp/)

Basiaclly this works:

```
var visible = $('#container').find(' > div:visible'),
    hidden = $('#container').find(' > div:hidden');

visible.fadeOut(1000, function() {
});
setTimeout(function() { hidden.fadeIn('slow') },1000);
```

and this doesn't:

```
var visible = $('#container').find(' > div:visible'),
    hidden = $('#container').find(' > div:hidden');

visible.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    hidden.fadeIn(100)
});
```

The second way makes the page freeze up.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm using the callback?

I need to be able to put it in an animation queue, because I need to be able to `stop()` everything.

Is there any way to make this work? I's broken on Chrome and FF

Comment: There should be a "Don't try this at home" label somewhere. Because guess what? It really freezes the browser!

Comment: Yeah, I did mention it though `The second way makes the page freeze up.`

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but I thought that it could be resolved by clicking on the "Stop script" button. In that case the button doesn't help, I had to kill the browser.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev: Any idea why that happens?

Comment: visible.animate({opactiy: 1.0 } fadeOut('slow', function() { hidden.fadeIn(100)
});
}
}, 3000);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256400/fading-elements-in-and-out-without-changing-the-layout-of-the-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your 2nd solution is, that an animation will be started for each visible div and for each animation (which has finished) all hidden divs start the fade in animation.

Comment: In other words, `.fadeIn()` is called way more times than the OP expects? Once for every fadeOut instead of once, at the end. I did notice that the animation eventually ends.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, first of all, why are you using such construction:

```
 $('#container').find(' > div:visible');
```

Just use:

```
 $('#container > div:visible');
```

Second, don't use `#container` because for some reason if fires fadeOut for **301** elements inside which is just too much.

Scratch that, i see jsfiddle has been changed and now it's only one element in there. Not surprised that it crashed before - too many objects.

Third, after fadeOut nothing fades in because at the point when you assign **hidden** variable there is no hidden divs. You'll have to use this in your callback:

```
 $('#container2 > div:hidden').fadeIn(1000)
```