# Expanding search bar over links

Tags: jquery, forms, search, css, expand

I am trying to have a search input that expands on focus and at the same time hides the other content in the parent div.

see it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/QF7ra/2/

It sort of works, but I need the parent div to remain the same size throughout.

thanks,
g

Comment: try to use e.preventDefault() in  click().Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QF7ra/3/

Comment: Duplicated with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256400/fading-elements-in-and-out-without-changing-the-layout-of-the-page

Answer (score 6):

This: http://jsfiddle.net/pVmWE/

Comment: @CoDeaDDict what's wrong with that? It's exactly what's needed. Setting the property to empty removes it, thus making it fall back to the property in the CSS file.

Comment: Like I said, setting the property to empty removes it. See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/) (search for `empty string`).