# How to use fadeIn() if the div is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I need to be able to smoothly fade In the div's which are hidden by default.

I am using this code:

```
$(".grey_cover").css({
    visibility: "visible"
}).fadeIn(2000, function () {
    $(".popup").css({
        visibility: "visible"
    }).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Div's `grey_cover` and `popup` have `visibility:hidden` by default.
This code is working but the div's are just pop in out so fast..this milliseconds are not doing anything..I have tried with `slow` option instead of `milliseconds` and there is still the same behavior.

I want to fade them slowly.

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2256424/1247955)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `visibility` for this but `display: none;`. And then remove the jQuery CSS parts. Than you should be fine.

Comment: thank you..this solved the problem. Can you give me some explanation? I would really like to know why these two are not doing the same thing?

Comment: The CSS properties `visibility` and `display` are not the same thing.  The `visibility` property determines whether the contents of the element are rendered.  The `display` property determines whether and how it is used in the determination of the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

css:

```
.grey_cover {
   visibility: visible;
   display: none;
}

.pop_up {
   visibility: visible;
   display: none;
}
```

javascript:

```
 $(".grey_cover").fadeIn(2000, function() { 
     $(".popup").fadeIn(3000);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't alter your CSS rules. You can set `opacity` to `0` along with `visibility` set to `visible`. Then `.animate()` can handle the animation.

```
$(".grey_cover").css({
    opacity: 0,
    visibility: "visible"
}).animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 2000, function() {
    $(".popup").css({
        opacity: 0,
        visibility: "visible"
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 3000);
});
```

Having said this, using `display` is better in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You're making them visible before fading them in - you don't need to make them visible, the fadeIn will handle that.