# Display:None destroys the rendering of other jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

So i have a jquery Multiple Select Dropdownbox (Checkboxes inside a drop down)
I was trying to implement [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/BC4eY/2/)  so that it would look like a Menu that will POP-out upon hover on the div provided. so here is my code

ASP Code:

```
<div class="box">
        SORT?
        <div class="hiddencolumn"  style="position: absolute; background-color:Black; height:auto;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="CompanyDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="RegionDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="AreaDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="BranchDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="StorageGroupDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="SORDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="TicketDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="KaratDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="PORIGINDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ClassificationsDropDownList" Class="s10" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="SortButton" runat="server" Text="Sort" OnClick="SortButton_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript For boxes dropdown checklist and hover fadein

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()      
        {                 

            $(".s10").dropdownchecklist( { firstItemChecksAll: true,forceMultiple: true, onComplete: function(selector) {
                var values = "";
                for( i=0; i < selector.options.length; i++ ) {
                    if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].value != "")) {
                        if ( values != "" ) values += ";";
                        values += selector.options[i].value;
                    }
                }
                alert( values );
            } }); 


            $(function(){
    $(".box").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".hiddencolumn").fadeIn();
    }
                    ,function(){
                        $(this).find(".hiddencolumn").fadeOut();
                    }
                   );        
});  

   }); 
    </script>
```

Css

```
.hiddencolumn
{
      display: none;
}
```

when i remove the Hidden column class on the Div (eg.Remove the `display:none;`)
Rendering is correct like this:
[image: a]
the problem is when i added the `hiddenColumn` Class or added `display:none` on the div this is what renders

[image: b]

Any help? or work around? any guide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display:none` to keep the space dedicated to the element in the layout.

Comment: @Anthony if i use `visibility: hidden` the jquery for `fadein()` doesn't work, so in case of of that even though i hover my mouse over the div it will not appear as i wanted, if you can give an alternative jquery please post it as an answer thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256400/fading-elements-in-and-out-without-changing-the-layout-of-the-page), you could replay your `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` with:

```
// FadeOut with visibility : hidden
$(this).find(".hiddencolumn").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).show().css({visibility: "hidden"});
});

// FadeIn with visibility : visible
$(this).find(".hiddencolumn").hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn("slow");
```

The problem is that `display: none` actually removes the element from layout, so it no longer has height or width that affect other elements, while simply changing the element's `opacity`, such as with `.animate({opacity:1})` makes the element 100% opaque but the element still responds to events, such as mouse clicks. `visibility: hidden` is the only CSS rule that renders the outline for the element in the layout but does not present it otherwise to the user.

Comment: This answer suits really well i just used `$(this).find(".hiddencolumn").hide().css({visibility: "visible"}).fadeIn("slow");` and for the hiding `function(){
                        $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
                    }
                   );        `

Answer (score 0):

use `max-height:0, overflow:hidden` initially, and on hover set `max-height:auto`.